# Awaiting asynchronous function blocks main thread

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm building a discord music bot with JavaScript (I just started learning yesterday, so the code might be a bit messy). So far, I've gotten it to add a song to a queue, play the song, then move to the next song once the current song is done. However, I've run into a small problem: the bot's music pauses for a split second every time I add a song to the queue while one is already playing. I've worked out that this is due to yt-search, a module I'm using to search youtube for a specific video.

Here's the relevant code inside *main.js*, the actual file that is run through Node.

```
    else if (cmd === 'play') {
    const connection = getVoiceConnection(msg.guildId);

    if (!connection) {
        const join = await client.modules.backend.join(msg);

        if (!join) return console.log('Unable to join');
    }

    if (!qMap.get(msg.guildId)) {
        console.log('No queue for this server, creating a new one');

        await client.modules.queue.construct(qMap, msg.guildId, msg.member.voice.channel, connection);
    }

    client.modules.queue.add(msg, qMap.get(msg.guildId), args, player);
```

Somebody uses the 'play' command to play a song; their search terms are passed to *queue.add* as *args* along with some other variables. *queue.add* is imported from another module; here's that code:

```
async function queueAddSong(msg, queue, terms, player) {

song = searchForVideo(msg, terms);

console.log(`Adding to queue: ${song.title}`);

queue.songs.push(song);

if (player.state.status === 'idle') startQueue(queue, player);
}
```

and here's `searchForVideo()`, which does the actual searching:

```
async function searchForVideo(msg, query) {

let song = {};

// Was a valid URL passed? If yes, use ytdl. Otherwise, search.
if (ytdl.validateURL(query[0])) {
    songInfo = await ytdl.getInfo(query[0]);

    song = {
        title: songInfo.videoDetails.title,
        url: songInfo.videoDetails.video_url
    };
} else {
    // Search
    const vidResults = await ytSearch(query.join(' '));

    if (vidResults.videos.length > 1) {
        song = {
            title: vidResults.videos[0].title,
            url: vidResults.videos[0].url
        };
    } else {
        msg.reply(':x: No results found');
        return null;
    }
}

return song;
}
```

and here's `startQueue()` that converts the song into a useable stream and plays it

```
function startQueue(queue, player) {
console.log(`Starting a new queue with song: ${queue.songs[0].title}`);
// Start a queue. Behavior is different from just switching songs, so I've made this a separate function.

const connection = getVoiceConnection(queue.voiceChannel.guildId);
const stream = ytdl(queue.songs[0].url, {
    filter: 'audioonly'
});
const resource = createAudioResource(stream, {
    inputType: StreamType.Arbitrary
});

// Play first song
player.play(resource);
connection.subscribe(player);

// Add event listener to play next song
player.on(AudioPlayerStatus.Idle, () => {
    if (queue.songs.length > 1) {
        console.log(`Song finished. Moving to: ${queue.songs[1].title}`);

        queue.songs.shift();
        playInQueue(queue, 0, player);
    } else {
        console.log(`Queue finished.`);
    }
});
}
```

It seems that `ytsearch` is intensive enough to stop the whole thread long enough to be noticeable. How can I run the search separate from the main thread so that, regardless of how much time or processing power searching takes, the music continues to play while it's searching?

Comment: How many results are you getting from the problem-causing call to `ytsearch()`?  Is it a large amount of data?  How is the music played from the bot?  Where is that code?  With properly written code, I wouldn't think you'd need to use a workerThread just for a network search unless you or the library spends a lot of cycles processing the result.

Comment: Not that many; roughly 15-20. I'm not super familiar with `ytsearch()`, so I'm not exactly sure how much data it's returning per result but it looks like a lot of strings. I was actually wrong, it's not **await** but the actual processing of `ytsearch()` that caused the stutter. I ended up solving it with a workerThread and I'm content with that since this is a small-scale personal project. To answer everything else, it's played with `voiceConnection`, `audioResource`, and `audioPlayer` from discord.js. I didn't include that code for the sake of brevity, but I'll edit the question with it now.

Comment: It seems like `song = searchForVideo(msg, terms);` is missing an `await` keyword?

Comment: What does `playInQueue` do?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, you're right, that was missing an `await`. `playInQueue()` does essentially the same thing that's done in `startQueue()` but without adding a new event listener. It just uses `ytdl` to make a new stream with the specified song, makes a new resource with that stream, then does `player.play(resource)`.

Answer (score 2):

I was actually wrong with the title; it's not the `await` part that caused the stutter, it was the `ytSearch()` function itself. It seems like something about calling that at all was intense enough to stop the whole thread long enough to be noticeable. While it's probably overkill for just searching youtube, I managed to solve this by giving `searchForVideo()` a worker thread separate from the main thread to work in. I can't accept my own answer yet so I'll leave this here for now.

Answer (score -2):

Consider removing `async` and `await` and replacing them with normal promise resolve approach.

```js
function searchForVideo(msg, query) {
  if (ytdl.validateURL(query[0])) {
    return ytdl.getInfo(query[0])
      .then(songInfo => {
        return {
          title: songInfo.videoDetails.title,
          url: songInfo.videoDetails.video_url
        }
      });
  } else {
    return ytSearch(query.join(' '))
      .then(vidResults => {
        if (vidResults.videos.length > 1) {
          return {
            title: vidResults.videos[0].title,
            url: vidResults.videos[0].url
          };
        } else {
          msg.reply(':x: No results found');
          return null;
        }
      });
  }
}
```

And then in your `queueAddSong` function, resolve the promise.

```js
function queueAddSong(msg, queue, terms, player) {
  searchForVideo(msg, terms).then(song => {
    console.log(`Adding to queue: ${song.title}`);
    queue.songs.push(song);
  });
  if (player.state.status === 'idle') startQueue(queue, player);
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `async`/`await`. What advantage do you think does a "*normal promise resolve approach*" have?

Comment: @Bergi, the difference is obviously `blocking` vs `unlbocking`. Simply try run the following code.
`
const foo = () => {
  return Promise.resolve(1)
}

const fun1 = async () =>{
  console.log('before calling foo in fun1')
  const result = await foo();
  console.log({result}, 'result in fun1');
  console.log('after calling foo in fun1')
}

const fun2 = () => {
  console.log('before calling foo in fun2')
  foo().then(result => {console.log({result}, 'result in fun2')});
  console.log('after calling foo in fun2');
}

fun1();
fun2();
`

Comment: @Bergi `await` will block the following code til the promise is resolved, while `.then` won't. The fact is if the following code relies on the resolved promise, then surely `asyn/await` is a great syntax sugar, but if the following code is completely irrelevant to the promise, then what's wrong of using `.then` to turn it into unblocking mode?

Comment: There is no code after the `.then()` in that function that would be "unblocked". You put all the code that was after the `await` inside the `then` callback, because it is *supposed* to wait.

Comment: @Bergi then the caller function will be blocked.

Comment: No, the caller of an `async function` is **not** blocked. It just returns a promise. Switching to `.then()` syntax changes nothing.

Comment: clearly there is code behind await `if (player.state.status === 'idle') startQueue(queue, player);`

Comment: But there is no `await` in front of the `startQueue()` call? And even if there was, it doesn't matter whether `startQueue` is implemented using `async`/`await` syntax or `then` syntax. (Not to say that you changed the code in `searchForVideo`, not in `startQueue`)